# How to make the Makefile echos to use `/bin/echo -e`?

Tags: makefile, echo

I know I can use this:

```make
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

And make will use `/bin/bash` shell. Can I do the same with `echo` command? For example:

```make
SHELL := /bin/bash
ECHO := /bin/echo -e

all:
    @echo Fixed echo?
```

I always thought that using `ECHOCMD := /bin/echo -e` on the top of my Makefile would do this. But after searching, I could not find any reference supporting that `ECHOCMD := /bin/echo -e` has any special meaning to change the default `@echo` command.

Is the only alternative to use:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
ECHO := /bin/echo -e

all:
    @${ECHO} Fixed echo?
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any version of make that ever treated `ECHOCMD` specially.  Certainly no version of make that I've ever heard of would parse your recipe looking for the static command `echo` and replace it with some other command.

Comment: But, you should not use `echo -e` anyway.  It's _highly_ non-portable.  If you want to use special characters you should be using `printf`.